# Adding column in Table, using UPDATE to populate data and then drop other column does not free space

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

**Scenario:** Adding column in Table, using UPDATE to populate data and then drop other column does not free space

**Note:** My Warehouse configuration is XL and is auto terminate after 5 minutes

Tables:

"database"."schema"."table1"

```
-- ID varchar(32),  eg: "ajs6djnd79dhashlj172883gdb4av3"
-- ........
```

"database"."schema"."id_dim"

```
-- ID varchar(32)    eg:  "ajs6djnd79dhashlj172883gdb4av3"
-- ID_NUM NUMBER(12, 0) AUTOINCREMENT START 1 INCREMENT 1  eg: 1
```

```
ALTER TABLE "database"."schema"."table1" ADD ID_NUM NUMBER(12, 0);


UPDATE  "database"."schema"."table1" e1
 SET e1.ID_NUM = d2.ID_NUM
FROM "database"."schema"."id_dim" d2
   WHERE e1.id = d2.id;


ALTER TABLE  "database"."schema"."table1" DROP ID;

ALTER TABLE  "database"."schema"."table1" RENAME COLUMN ID_NUM TO ID;
```

**Q:** I am still seeing that after UPDATE operation and column drop, memory consumption is more as compared to previous table size and in Snowflake doc it says that micro-partitions is written after DML operation.

Comment: Did you consider that time travel keeps the data around in case you want to recover it? Did you configure it to 0?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, you are right: A new micro-partition is written after your DML operation.

But: This does not mean the old micro-partition is dropped. Here Time Travel comes into play and the older version is still stored.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-time-travel.html

How long the old data is stored? This depends on your table type as well as the value of your parameter DATA_RETENTION_TIME_IN_DAYS for the object: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#data-retention-time-in-days